# Outbound Message Security and Validation

Tags: security, workflowoutboundmessage

I am investigating the security implications of using Salesforce's Outbound Messages. I have reviewed the [documentation about security](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm) for Outbound Messages.

Does Salesforce have a way of guaranteeing that a request from an Outbound Message is in fact from our Organization?

I realize they pass the `OrganizationId` field in the Outbound Message. 
I was hoping that Salesforce had a certificate approach that would be unique per organization instead of having to validate the `OrganizationId` sent with every request.

Comment: Indeed, I think the Salesforce documentation on this subject does a poor job at pointing out that the client certificate does not ensure the message is from your organization in particular.     It is mentioned, but in my opinion it should be flagged, bolded,  and alert-danger'd.     I'm sure some people follow the instructions, think they are secure, but anybody can register a Salesforce dev account and bypass their "security" if the org id is not also verified.    If you don't verify the Org ID, technically you only have security by obscurity.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read the part in your linked document about:

> If the configuration of your application (endpoint) server's SSL/TLS
>   allows, validate the identity of the Salesforce server when it takes
>   the role of a client to your server, using the Salesforce client
>   certificate. For instructions to download the certificate, see
>   Downloading the Salesforce Client Certificate.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm#om_client_cert

Or does not that satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yes I did. We currently have two Salesforce production instances. When I downloaded the certificate for both instances and compared them, they were identical.